# Chatbot problem - infinite recursion - Codecademy question

Tags: regex, python-3.x, chatbot

I'm learning how to code using Codecademy and I am really stuck on a question, and would love to be pointed in the right direction!

The code for the most part works, I just cannot get it to respond to the .match_reply function correctly. The idea is that the chatbot should identify the regex in self.alienbabble and respond with the appropriate answer. However, it is bugging out with an infinite recursion of all the responses of that function.

```
# importing regex and random libraries
import re
import random

class AlienBot:
  # potential negative responses
  negative_responses = ("no", "nope", "nah", "naw", "not a chance", "sorry")
  # keywords for exiting the conversation
  exit_commands = ("quit", "pause", "exit", "goodbye", "bye", "later")
  # random starter questions
  random_questions = (
        "Why are you here? ",
        "Are there many humans like you? ",
        "What do you consume for sustenance? ",
        "Is there intelligent life on this planet? ",
        "Does Earth have a leader? ",
        "What planets have you visited? ",
        "What technology do you have on this planet? "
    )

  def __init__(self):
    self.alienbabble = {'describe_planet_intent': '.*\s*your planet.*','answer_why_intent': 'why\sare.*', 'cubed_intent': '.*cube.*(\d+)'}

  # Define .greet() below:
  def greet(self):
    self.name = input("Hello. What is your name?")
    will_help = input(f"Hi {self.name}, I'm Etcetera. I'm not from this planet. Will you help me learn about your planet? ")
    if will_help in self.negative_responses:
      print ("Ok, have a nice Earth day!")
      return
    self.chat()

  # Define .make_exit() here:
  def make_exit(self, reply):
    for word in self.exit_commands:
      if word in reply:
        print ("Ok, have a nice Earth day!")
        return True

  # Define .chat() next:
  def chat(self):
    reply = input(random.choice(self.random_questions)).lower()
    while not self.make_exit(reply):
      reply = input(self.match_reply(reply))

  # Define .match_reply() below:
  def match_reply(self, reply):
    for key, value in self.alienbabble.items():
      intent = key
      regex = value
      #regex = 'describe_planet_intent'
      #reply = input(random.choice(self.random_questions)).lower()
      found_match = re.match(regex, reply)
      if found_match and intent == 'describe_planet_intent':
        return self.describe_planet_intent()
      elif found_match and intent == 'answer_why_intent':
        return self.answer_why_intent()
      elif found_match and intent == 'cubed_intent':
        return self.cubed_intent(found_match.groups()[0])
      else:
        return self.no_match_intent()

  # Define .describe_planet_intent():
  def describe_planet_intent(self):
    responses = ("My planet is a utopia of diverse organisms and species. ", "I am from Opidipus, the capital of the Wayward Galaxies. ")
    return random.choice(responses)

  # Define .answer_why_intent():
  def answer_why_intent(self):
    responses = ("I come in peace. ", "I am here to collect data on your planet and its inhabitants. ", "I heard the coffee is good. ")
    return random.choice(responses)

  # Define .cubed_intent():
  def cubed_intent(self, number):
    number = int(number)
    cubed_number = number * number * number
    return (f"The cube of {number} is {cubed_number}. Isn't that cool? ")

  # Define .no_match_intent():
  def no_match_intent(self):
    responses = ("Please tell me more. ", "Tell me more! ", "Why do you say that? ", "I see. Can you elaborate? ", "Interesting. Can you tell me more? ", "I see. How do you think? ", "Why? ", "How do you think I feel when you say that? ")
    return random.choice(responses)

# Create an instance of AlienBot below:
my_bot = AlienBot()
my_bot.greet()
```

I feel like there is a really simple solution to this, I've only been coding for 1 week so this is really new to me, and I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Did my answer help you understand what was the problem? if so, please mark it as accepted by marking the V to its left. If not, let me know so I can further help you with it.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your help. However I'm still unsure what 'reply' and 'regex' should be in order for the bot to identify the regex in the user's response and answer appropriately. Any guidance would be great!

Comment: In order to answer that, I need to see an updated code (where the infinite loop bug is fixed) so I could clearly understand the program flow, and then I could give you an answer for that. Can you update your code?

Comment: I've updated it :)

Comment: There's still something quite confusing with your code: You use your regex upon the *user* reply, but those regex strings are part of the *alien* answer (for example, the string `your planet`). This implies that you expect the user the input a *question* when replying to the alien. is that correct? if not, please lay out the user-alien conversation flow.

Comment: Yes I believe that's correct. It doesn't make much sense to me either but I'm just following the instructions on Codecademy

Comment: I added the additional info to my answer

Comment: Thanks for that! For some reason it's only working for the first intent 'describe_planet_intent'. It doesn't seem to recognize any regex associated with 'answer_why_intent' or 'cubed_intent'.

Comment: Can you explain what do you expect to match with the ones who don't work?

Comment: For example if I asked 'why are you here' that should match the regex 'why\sare.*' and the intent 'answer_why_intent' and the bot should reply with one of those responses. Or if I asked about the cube of a number it should match with the '.*cube.*(\d+)' regex and the 'cubed_intent'.

Comment: That solved that problem! Thank you. Now for some reason, when it runs the cubed statement, it is returning list has no attributes groups. I think if I can get this one error fixed then it will work. 

lif found_match and intent == 'cubed_intent':
        return self.cubed_intent(found_match.groups()[0])

Comment: @Nattaacker, see my edit, you can just omit the call for `groups()`

Comment: Is it working for you now? If you consider it done, please mark my answer as accepted by marking the V to its left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is indeed simple. Let's reduce your code to a minimally reproducible one:

```
def match_reply(self, reply):
    for key, value in self.alienbabble.items():
      # I omitted the 3 lines that were here - defining 'intent', 'regex_pattern' and 'regex' - 
      # since at this point they're yet not used
      reply = input(self.match_reply(reply)) # oops! self.match_reply is called again!
```

As you can see, you recursively call `self.match_reply` without anything to stop it.

EDIT:

There are another 2 things you need to fix:

1. Let's change `match_reply`:

   a. Let's give it the more appropriate name `match_alien_response`.
   b. Let's make it do what it should: just match a reply. Thus, we don't need it to get another input from the user.
   c. Let's make sure it iterates all the keys in `alienbabble` and doesn't return immediately.
   d. We need to use `re.findall` to get all matches in a string

   All these changes give us the following code:

   ```
   def match_alien_response(self, userReply):
     found = False
     for intent, regPattern in self.alienbabble.items():
       found_match = re.findall(regPattern, userReply)
       if found_match and intent == 'describe_planet_intent':
         return self.describe_planet_intent()
       elif found_match and intent == 'answer_why_intent':
         return self.answer_why_intent()
       elif found_match and intent == 'cubed_intent':
         return self.cubed_intent(found_match[0])
     if not found:
       return self.no_match_intent()
   ```
2. Inside `no_match_intent`, it should be `responses =` instead of `responses:`